# The GC log make me confused

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jstack

After question [All thread are blocked,like STW,and no responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34636916/all-thread-are-blocked-like-stw-and-no-responding),i added some JAVA_OPTS.

Here is my new opts.

```
 -server -Xms32g -Xmx32g \
 -XX:NewSize=10g -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly \
 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics -XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1 \
 -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime \
 -XX:+PrintGCCause -Xloggc:/var/log/flume-ng/gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M
```

And the app stoped working just now.

Here are the last lines of `gc log`(the last word of the `gc log` was `stopped:`).

```
2016-01-09T18:37:14.193+0800: 18879.031: Application time: 0.0071232 seconds
2016-01-09T18:37:14.193+0800: 18879.032: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0003769 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000800 seconds
2016-01-09T18:37:21.704+0800: 18886.542: Application time: 7.5105681 seconds
2016-01-09T18:37:21.705+0800: 18886.543: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2016-01-09T18:37:21.705+0800: 18886.543: [ParNew: 8412583K->36040K(9437184K), 0.0159936 secs] 21350038K->12973495K(32505856K), 0.0162151 secs] [Times: user=0.34 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2016-01-09T18:37:21.721+0800: 18886.559: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0172971 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001286 seconds
2016-01-09T18:37:37.830+0800: 18902.668: Application time: 16.1087180 seconds
2016-01-09T18:42:43.301+0800: 19208.140: Total time for which application threads were stopped:
```

Then,i used `jstack -m` command.Then the app came back to normal.

Here is the next gc log(first line's `305.4698351 second` is  i execute the `jstack command`'s time  subtract the app stopped working's time).

```
2016-01-09T18:42:43.301+0800: 19208.140: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 305.4715152 seconds, Stopping threads took: 305.4698351 seconds

skip some Application time log


2016-01-09T18:42:44.340+0800: 19209.179: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2016-01-09T18:42:44.340+0800: 19209.179: [ParNew: 8424650K->127192K(9437184K), 0.0331325 secs] 21362105K->13064648K(32505856K), 0.0333109 secs] [Times: user=0.72 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2016-01-09T18:42:44.374+0800: 19209.212: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0338915 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000998 seconds
2016-01-09T18:42:44.374+0800: 19209.212: Application time: 0.0001254 seconds
2016-01-09T18:42:44.375+0800: 19209.213: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) 2016-01-09T18:42:44.375+0800: 19209.213: [ParNew: 133268K->152503K(9437184K), 0.0335528 secs] 13070724K->13089959K(32505856K), 0.0336755 secs] [Times: user=0.69 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs] 
2016-01-09T18:42:44.408+0800: 19209.247: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0345724 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001147 seconds
2016-01-09T18:42:46.920+0800: 19211.759: Application time: 0.8197406 seconds
2016-01-09T18:42:46.921+0800: 19211.760: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2016-01-09T18:42:46.921+0800: 19211.760: [ParNew: 8541111K->441557K(9437184K), 0.0993869 secs] 21478567K->13379018K(32505856K), 0.0995702 secs] [Times: user=2.25 sys=0.00, real=0.10 secs] 
2016-01-09T18:42:49.571+0800: 19214.409: Application time: 0.6178457 seconds
2016-01-09T18:42:49.572+0800: 19214.410: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2016-01-09T18:42:49.572+0800: 19214.410: [ParNew: 8830165K->812963K(9437184K), 0.1568946 secs] 21767626K->13750433K(32505856K), 0.1571136 secs] [Times: user=3.58 sys=0.00, real=0.16 secs] 
2016-01-09T18:42:49.729+0800: 19214.568: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.1581075 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001236 seconds

2016-01-09T18:42:52.286+0800: 19217.125: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) 2016-01-09T18:42:52.286+0800: 19217.125: [ParNew: 9201571K->973385K(9437184K), 0.3264006 secs] 22139041K->14095607K(32505856K), 0.3265784 secs] [Times: user=4.46 sys=0.00, real=0.33 secs] 

2016-01-09T18:42:55.279+0800: 19220.117: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2016-01-09T18:42:55.279+0800: 19220.117: [ParNew: 9361993K->1048576K(9437184K), 0.3140569 secs] 22484215K->14506810K(32505856K), 0.3142791 secs] [Times: user=5.36 sys=0.00, real=0.31 secs] 

2016-01-09T18:42:58.222+0800: 19223.061: Application time: 0.0000301 seconds
2016-01-09T18:42:58.223+0800: 19223.061: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) 2016-01-09T18:42:58.223+0800: 19223.061: [ParNew: 9437184K->1048576K(9437184K), 0.3384320 secs] 22895418K->14892045K(32505856K), 0.3386214 secs] [Times: user=5.71 sys=0.00, real=0.34 secs] 

2016-01-09T18:43:01.166+0800: 19226.005: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) 2016-01-09T18:43:01.166+0800: 19226.005: [ParNew: 9437184K->1048576K(9437184K), 0.3425942 secs] 23280717K->15266436K(32505856K), 0.3427797 secs] [Times: user=5.89 sys=0.00, real=0.35 secs] 

2016-01-09T18:43:04.112+0800: 19228.950: Application time: 0.6938848 seconds
```

At the time `2016-01-09 18:43` the app stopped working again.

Then i used `jstack -m` command again,and the app came back to ok again.

Here is the gc log.

```
2016-01-09T18:46:18.871+0800: 19423.709: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2016-01-09T18:46:18.871+0800: 19423.710: [ParNew: 9437184K->1048576K(9437184K), 0.3188298 secs] 23655044K->15632857K(32505856K), 0.3191140 secs] [Times: user=5.55 sys=0.00, real=0.32 secs] 
2016-01-09T18:46:19.190+0800: 19424.029: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 195.0782503 seconds, Stopping threads took: 194.7573545 seconds


2016-01-09T18:46:22.197+0800: 19427.035: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2016-01-09T18:46:22.197+0800: 19427.036: [ParNew: 9437184K->1048576K(9437184K), 0.3175688 secs] 24021465K->16017865K(32505856K), 0.3177865 secs] [Times: user=5.85 sys=0.00, real=0.32 secs] 

2016-01-09T18:46:25.111+0800: 19429.950: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2016-01-09T18:46:25.112+0800: 19429.950: [ParNew: 9437184K->1048576K(9437184K), 0.2808750 secs] 24406473K->16384589K(32505856K), 0.2810767 secs] [Times: user=5.04 sys=0.00, real=0.28 secs] 

2016-01-09T18:46:27.974+0800: 19432.813: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2016-01-09T18:46:27.975+0800: 19432.813: [ParNew: 9437184K->1048576K(9437184K), 0.3201238 secs] 24773197K->16833663K(32505856K), 0.3203207 secs] [Times: user=5.53 sys=0.00, real=0.32 secs] 
.........
2016-01-09T18:55:25.249+0800: 19970.088: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2016-01-09T18:55:25.249+0800: 19970.088: [ParNew: 8419546K->31852K(9437184K), 0.0155374 secs] 13769434K->5382550K(32505856K), 0.0157411 secs] [Times: user=0.33 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
```

I found,after i execute `jstack -m` command,the `GC log ParNew: from size->to size(9437184K)` was abnormal,the `to size` became bigger and bigger like some memory could not be released.But i execute `jstack -m` the second time,the to size became small after a period of time.

When the system was not normal, The `jstack` command must add the option `-F`,and `jmap` need to perform a few hours.

Here is a special thread in the `jstack -F` result file.And all threads's state are blocked except in_vm.

```
Attaching to process ID 23694, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.66-b17
Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.

Thread 143283: (state = IN_VM)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.freeMemory(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.nio.DirectByteBuffer$Deallocator.run() @bci=17, line=94 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.misc.Cleaner.clean() @bci=12, line=143 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.util.internal.Cleaner0.freeDirectBuffer(java.nio.ByteBuffer) @bci=34, line=66 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0.freeDirectBuffer(java.nio.ByteBuffer) @bci=1, line=147 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.freeDirectBuffer(java.nio.ByteBuffer) @bci=13, line=281 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.freeDirect(java.nio.ByteBuffer) @bci=1, line=115 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.deallocate() @bci=24, line=508 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release() @bci=39, line=106 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.release(java.lang.Object) @bci=11, line=59 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.safeRelease(java.lang.Object) @bci=1, line=84 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove() @bci=40, line=258 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.removeBytes(long) @bci=83, line=334 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer) @bci=238, line=317 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0() @bci=89, line=750 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0() @bci=9, line=303 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush() @bci=15, line=719 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext) @bci=4, line=1119 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush() @bci=8, line=735 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1500(io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext) @bci=1, line=32 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$16.run() @bci=4, line=723 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(long) @bci=26, line=357 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run() @bci=106, line=357 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run() @bci=13, line=111 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)
```

Here is my environment.

```
java version "1.8.0_66"
Linux version 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Linux version 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64

It looks like you're using a kernel suffering from the [futex_wait bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mechanical-sympathy/QbmpZxp6C64).

The solution is to update to a newer kernel.

Comment: Why the ParNew log was abnormal.

Comment: What makes you suspect that this kernel bug is the cause?

Comment: @AngusLee read the linked mailing list conversation. The symptoms match.

Answer (score -2):

It seems a memory issue.

Cases:

- You may have declared some variables inside loops. Create those variables in outside loop.
- You need to increase your heap size.

Comment: I added the heap size to 50G before,But the app stopped the same..When the app stopped working,it could not recover itself until i use jstack command. So i want to know which code has problem.

Comment: @famoss Profile your application.

Comment: @Kayaman,my app is a flume app,but the sink is not the official sink,it coded by myself.

Comment: @Kayaman,The sink has a lot of code,I don't know where to start the profile.Help me.

Comment: @famoss You don't know how to profile an application, do you. Off to Google you go then.

Comment: @Kayaman,Thank you,i will use findbugs to profile my application.According to your experience,which reason can make all thread's state are blocked except STW.What is the most probable cause of my problem？

Comment: @famoss FindBugs is not a profiler! What on earth did you Google for?